# Is there a name for $\max \| A x \|$ for all $\|x\|=1?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a name for $\max \| A x \|$ for all $\|x\|=1?$

($A$ is a matrix, and $x$ is a vector)

One might be inclined to guess that it's the spectral radius of $A$, but that's not true. I'm wondering if there is a special term for this property of $A$.

Comment: IT is often written as $\|A\|.$

Comment: Notice that in infinite dimension the maximum might not exist. All the answers you have received apply to the supremum in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the norm of a linear map or the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm). It checks "how much does this matrix stretch values."

It is a theorem that $$\mathrm{Sup}_{x \in X}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\mathrm{Sup}_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|.$$

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is an accepted term for the nonlinear version? $\mathrm{Sup}_{x \ne y} ( \|f(x) - f(y)\| / \|x - y\| )$ ?

Comment: Yes. If $X,Y$ are more generally metric spaces and $f:X \to Y$, then I would call that the lipschitz constant.

Answer (score 4):

It is called the induced matrix norm. If the underlying vector norm is the Euclidean one, then it is also called the largest singular value.

Answer (score 2):

Can be called a *subordinate norm*.

Comment: yes and we use three bars $||| A |||$ to differentiate from other norms which does not necessarily come from the vectorial norm.

Answer (score 1):

It goes by the name of [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm). It's equal to $\sqrt{\rho(A^HA)}$ when the norms are the usual euclidean ones.

Comment: $\rho(A^tA)$ is the absolute value of the largest eigenvalue? I guess "spectral radius"?

Comment: Yes, the largest module of an eigenvalue. Spectral radius, in other words.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, it is called the operator norm (more precisely the operator norm of the linear transformation induced by the map $x \to Ax$).

I will add that it is frequently used in real analysis to "bound things". In particular, the operator norm satisfies the following (extremely) useful property:

$$\Vert Ax \Vert \leq \Vert A \Vert  \Vert x \Vert \quad \text{for all }x$$

Comment: Do you happen to know what that property is called?

Comment: @MaxB sub-multiplicative if memory serves

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's also called the [natural norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNorm.html).